# Page break in print window: table borders not showing

Tags: html, css

I am trying to build a printable Website (Print to PDF to be exact) using HTML and CSS. I am using a table on my website and I am using page-break-inside: avoid preventing pages at certain places.

Now my Problem:
if the page breaks inside the table the vertical table borders aren't showing on the next page (see Image).

Can anyone help?
Here's a full html document for testing:

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 95%;
  margin-left: 2.5%;
  border-top: 2px;
  margin-top: 70px;
}

th {
  background-color: #FFCC00;
  text-align: center;
}

td {
  text-align: center;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

thead {
  page-break-inside: avoid;
  background-color: #FFCC00;
  margin: 0;
  page-break-after: avoid;
}

tbody {
  /*border: 2px solid black;*/
  page-break-inside: avoid;
  break-inside: avoid;
}

.emptywithborder {
  border: 2px solid black !important;
}

.single_note {
  background-color: #EBF1DE;
}

.empty {
  border: 0;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <table>
    <caption>Jugend 1</caption>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="rank">Rang</th>
        <th class="Team">Team</th>
        <th class="gender"></th>
        <th class="discipline">Boden</th>
        <th class="discipline">Trampolin</th>
        <th class="discipline">Tumbling</th>
        <th class="Total">TOTAL</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>21 - KTV - J1 w</td>
        <td>weiblich</td>
        <td class="emptywithborder">16.400</td>
        <td class="emptywithborder">11.550</td>
        <td class="emptywithborder">12.650</td>
        <td>40.600</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="empty"></td>
        <td class="empty"></td>
        <td class="single_note">E</td>
        <td class="single_note">6.100</td>
        <td class="single_note">6.350</td>
        <td class="single_note">6.650</td>
        <td class="empty"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="empty"></td>
        <td class="empty"></td>
        <td class="single_note">D</td>
        <td class="single_note">6.300</td>
        <td class="single_note">3.200</td>
        <td class="single_note">4.100</td>
        <td class="empty"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="empty"></td>
        <td class="empty"></td>
        <td class="single_note">C</td>
        <td class="single_note">4.000</td>
        <td class="single_note">2.000</td>
        <td class="single_note">1.900</td>
        <td class="empty"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <!--OK minus note-->
        <td class="empty"></td>
        <td class="empty"></td>
        <td class="single_note">OK-</td>
        <td class="emptywithborder single_note">-</td>
        <td class="emptywithborder single_note">-</td>
        <td class="emptywithborder single_note">-</td>
        <td class="empty"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="empty"></td>
        <td class="empty"></td>
        <td class="single_note">OK+</td>
        <td class="emptywithborder single_note">-</td>
        <td class="emptywithborder single_note">-</td>
        <td class="emptywithborder single_note">-</td>
        <td class="empty"></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>20 - TS Hohenems - J1 w</td>
        <td>weiblich</td>
        <td class="emptywithborder"></td>
        <td class="emptywithborder"></td>
        <td class="emptywithborder">13.350</td>
        <td>13.350</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="empty"></td>
        <td class="empty"></td>
        <td class="single_note">E</td>
        <td class="emptywithborder single_note">-</td>
        <td class="emptywithborder single_note">-</td>
        <td class="single_note">7.350</td>
        <td class="empty"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="empty"></td>
        <td class="empty"></td>
        <td class="single_note">D</td>
        <td class="emptywithborder single_note">-</td>
        <td class="emptywithborder single_note">-</td>
        <td class="single_note">4.000</td>
        <td class="empty"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="empty"></td>
        <td class="empty"></td>
        <td class="single_note">C</td>
        <td class="emptywithborder single_note">-</td>
        <td class="emptywithborder single_note">-</td>
        <td class="single_note">2.000</td>
        <td class="empty"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <!--OK minus note-->
        <td class="empty"></td>
        <td class="empty"></td>
        <td class="single_note">OK-</td>
        <td class="emptywithborder single_note">-</td>
        <td class="emptywithborder single_note">-</td>
        <td class="emptywithborder single_note">-</td>
        <td class="empty"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="empty"></td>
        <td class="empty"></td>
        <td class="single_note">OK+</td>
        <td class="emptywithborder single_note">-</td>
        <td class="emptywithborder single_note">-</td>
        <td class="emptywithborder single_note">-</td>
        <td class="empty"></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <table>
    <caption>Jugend 1</caption>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="rank">Rang</th>
        <th class="Team">Team</th>
        <th class="gender"></th>
        <th class="discipline">Boden</th>
        <th class="discipline">Trampolin</th>
        <th class="discipline">Tumbling</th>
        <th class="Total">TOTAL</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>21 - KTV - J1 w</td>
        <td>weiblich</td>
        <td class="emptywithborder">16.400</td>
        <td class="emptywithborder">11.550</td>
        <td class="emptywithborder">12.650</td>
        <td>40.600</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="empty"></td>
        <td class="empty"></td>
        <td class="single_note">E</td>
        <td class="single_note">6.100</td>
        <td class="single_note">6.350</td>
        <td class="single_note">6.650</td>
        <td class="empty"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="empty"></td>
        <td class="empty"></td>
        <td class="single_note">D</td>
        <td class="single_note">6.300</td>
        <td class="single_note">3.200</td>
        <td class="single_note">4.100</td>
        <td class="empty"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="empty"></td>
        <td class="empty"></td>
        <td class="single_note">C</td>
        <td class="single_note">4.000</td>
        <td class="single_note">2.000</td>
        <td class="single_note">1.900</td>
        <td class="empty"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <!--OK minus note-->
        <td class="empty"></td>
        <td class="empty"></td>
        <td class="single_note">OK-</td>
        <td class="emptywithborder single_note">-</td>
        <td class="emptywithborder single_note">-</td>
        <td class="emptywithborder single_note">-</td>
        <td class="empty"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="empty"></td>
        <td class="empty"></td>
        <td class="single_note">OK+</td>
        <td class="emptywithborder single_note">-</td>
        <td class="emptywithborder single_note">-</td>
        <td class="emptywithborder single_note">-</td>
        <td class="empty"></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>20 - TS Hohenems - J1 w</td>
        <td>weiblich</td>
        <td class="emptywithborder"></td>
        <td class="emptywithborder"></td>
        <td class="emptywithborder">13.350</td>
        <td>13.350</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="empty"></td>
        <td class="empty"></td>
        <td class="single_note">E</td>
        <td class="emptywithborder single_note">-</td>
        <td class="emptywithborder single_note">-</td>
        <td class="single_note">7.350</td>
        <td class="empty"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="empty"></td>
        <td class="empty"></td>
        <td class="single_note">D</td>
        <td class="emptywithborder single_note">-</td>
        <td class="emptywithborder single_note">-</td>
        <td class="single_note">4.000</td>
        <td class="empty"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="empty"></td>
        <td class="empty"></td>
        <td class="single_note">C</td>
        <td class="emptywithborder single_note">-</td>
        <td class="emptywithborder single_note">-</td>
        <td class="single_note">2.000</td>
        <td class="empty"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <!--OK minus note-->
        <td class="empty"></td>
        <td class="empty"></td>
        <td class="single_note">OK-</td>
        <td class="emptywithborder single_note">-</td>
        <td class="emptywithborder single_note">-</td>
        <td class="emptywithborder single_note">-</td>
        <td class="empty"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="empty"></td>
        <td class="empty"></td>
        <td class="single_note">OK+</td>
        <td class="emptywithborder single_note">-</td>
        <td class="emptywithborder single_note">-</td>
        <td class="emptywithborder single_note">-</td>
        <td class="empty"></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <table>
    <caption>Jugend 1</caption>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="rank">Rang</th>
        <th class="Team">Team</th>
        <th class="gender"></th>
        <th class="discipline">Boden</th>
        <th class="discipline">Trampolin</th>
        <th class="discipline">Tumbling</th>
        <th class="Total">TOTAL</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>21 - KTV - J1 w</td>
        <td>weiblich</td>
        <td class="emptywithborder">16.400</td>
        <td class="emptywithborder">11.550</td>
        <td class="emptywithborder">12.650</td>
        <td>40.600</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="empty"></td>
        <td class="empty"></td>
        <td class="single_note">E</td>
        <td class="single_note">6.100</td>
        <td class="single_note">6.350</td>
        <td class="single_note">6.650</td>
        <td class="empty"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="empty"></td>
        <td class="empty"></td>
        <td class="single_note">D</td>
        <td class="single_note">6.300</td>
        <td class="single_note">3.200</td>
        <td class="single_note">4.100</td>
        <td class="empty"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="empty"></td>
        <td class="empty"></td>
        <td class="single_note">C</td>
        <td class="single_note">4.000</td>
        <td class="single_note">2.000</td>
        <td class="single_note">1.900</td>
        <td class="empty"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <!--OK minus note-->
        <td class="empty"></td>
        <td class="empty"></td>
        <td class="single_note">OK-</td>
        <td class="emptywithborder single_note">-</td>
        <td class="emptywithborder single_note">-</td>
        <td class="emptywithborder single_note">-</td>
        <td class="empty"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="empty"></td>
        <td class="empty"></td>
        <td class="single_note">OK+</td>
        <td class="emptywithborder single_note">-</td>
        <td class="emptywithborder single_note">-</td>
        <td class="emptywithborder single_note">-</td>
        <td class="empty"></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>20 - TS Hohenems - J1 w</td>
        <td>weiblich</td>
        <td class="emptywithborder"></td>
        <td class="emptywithborder"></td>
        <td class="emptywithborder">13.350</td>
        <td>13.350</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="empty"></td>
        <td class="empty"></td>
        <td class="single_note">E</td>
        <td class="emptywithborder single_note">-</td>
        <td class="emptywithborder single_note">-</td>
        <td class="single_note">7.350</td>
        <td class="empty"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="empty"></td>
        <td class="empty"></td>
        <td class="single_note">D</td>
        <td class="emptywithborder single_note">-</td>
        <td class="emptywithborder single_note">-</td>
        <td class="single_note">4.000</td>
        <td class="empty"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="empty"></td>
        <td class="empty"></td>
        <td class="single_note">C</td>
        <td class="emptywithborder single_note">-</td>
        <td class="emptywithborder single_note">-</td>
        <td class="single_note">2.000</td>
        <td class="empty"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <!--OK minus note-->
        <td class="empty"></td>
        <td class="empty"></td>
        <td class="single_note">OK-</td>
        <td class="emptywithborder single_note">-</td>
        <td class="emptywithborder single_note">-</td>
        <td class="emptywithborder single_note">-</td>
        <td class="empty"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="empty"></td>
        <td class="empty"></td>
        <td class="single_note">OK+</td>
        <td class="emptywithborder single_note">-</td>
        <td class="emptywithborder single_note">-</td>
        <td class="emptywithborder single_note">-</td>
        <td class="empty"></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <table>
    <caption>Jugend 1</caption>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="rank">Rang</th>
        <th class="Team">Team</th>
        <th class="gender"></th>
        <th class="discipline">Boden</th>
        <th class="discipline">Trampolin</th>
        <th class="discipline">Tumbling</th>
        <th class="Total">TOTAL</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>21 - KTV - J1 w</td>
        <td>weiblich</td>
        <td class="emptywithborder">16.400</td>
        <td class="emptywithborder">11.550</td>
        <td class="emptywithborder">12.650</td>
        <td>40.600</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="empty"></td>
        <td class="empty"></td>
        <td class="single_note">E</td>
        <td class="single_note">6.100</td>
        <td class="single_note">6.350</td>
        <td class="single_note">6.650</td>
        <td class="empty"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="empty"></td>
        <td class="empty"></td>
        <td class="single_note">D</td>
        <td class="single_note">6.300</td>
        <td class="single_note">3.200</td>
        <td class="single_note">4.100</td>
        <td class="empty"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="empty"></td>
        <td class="empty"></td>
        <td class="single_note">C</td>
        <td class="single_note">4.000</td>
        <td class="single_note">2.000</td>
        <td class="single_note">1.900</td>
        <td class="empty"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <!--OK minus note-->
        <td class="empty"></td>
        <td class="empty"></td>
        <td class="single_note">OK-</td>
        <td class="emptywithborder single_note">-</td>
        <td class="emptywithborder single_note">-</td>
        <td class="emptywithborder single_note">-</td>
        <td class="empty"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="empty"></td>
        <td class="empty"></td>
        <td class="single_note">OK+</td>
        <td class="emptywithborder single_note">-</td>
        <td class="emptywithborder single_note">-</td>
        <td class="emptywithborder single_note">-</td>
        <td class="empty"></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>20 - TS Hohenems - J1 w</td>
        <td>weiblich</td>
        <td class="emptywithborder"></td>
        <td class="emptywithborder"></td>
        <td class="emptywithborder">13.350</td>
        <td>13.350</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="empty"></td>
        <td class="empty"></td>
        <td class="single_note">E</td>
        <td class="emptywithborder single_note">-</td>
        <td class="emptywithborder single_note">-</td>
        <td class="single_note">7.350</td>
        <td class="empty"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="empty"></td>
        <td class="empty"></td>
        <td class="single_note">D</td>
        <td class="emptywithborder single_note">-</td>
        <td class="emptywithborder single_note">-</td>
        <td class="single_note">4.000</td>
        <td class="empty"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="empty"></td>
        <td class="empty"></td>
        <td class="single_note">C</td>
        <td class="emptywithborder single_note">-</td>
        <td class="emptywithborder single_note">-</td>
        <td class="single_note">2.000</td>
        <td class="empty"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <!--OK minus note-->
        <td class="empty"></td>
        <td class="empty"></td>
        <td class="single_note">OK-</td>
        <td class="emptywithborder single_note">-</td>
        <td class="emptywithborder single_note">-</td>
        <td class="emptywithborder single_note">-</td>
        <td class="empty"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="empty"></td>
        <td class="empty"></td>
        <td class="single_note">OK+</td>
        <td class="emptywithborder single_note">-</td>
        <td class="emptywithborder single_note">-</td>
        <td class="emptywithborder single_note">-</td>
        <td class="empty"></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <table>
    <caption>Jugend 1</caption>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="rank">Rang</th>
        <th class="Team">Team</th>
        <th class="gender"></th>
        <th class="discipline">Boden</th>
        <th class="discipline">Trampolin</th>
        <th class="discipline">Tumbling</th>
        <th class="Total">TOTAL</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>21 - KTV - J1 w</td>
        <td>weiblich</td>
        <td class="emptywithborder">16.400</td>
        <td class="emptywithborder">11.550</td>
        <td class="emptywithborder">12.650</td>
        <td>40.600</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="empty"></td>
        <td class="empty"></td>
        <td class="single_note">E</td>
        <td class="single_note">6.100</td>
        <td class="single_note">6.350</td>
        <td class="single_note">6.650</td>
        <td class="empty"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="empty"></td>
        <td class="empty"></td>
        <td class="single_note">D</td>
        <td class="single_note">6.300</td>
        <td class="single_note">3.200</td>
        <td class="single_note">4.100</td>
        <td class="empty"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="empty"></td>
        <td class="empty"></td>
        <td class="single_note">C</td>
        <td class="single_note">4.000</td>
        <td class="single_note">2.000</td>
        <td class="single_note">1.900</td>
        <td class="empty"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <!--OK minus note-->
        <td class="empty"></td>
        <td class="empty"></td>
        <td class="single_note">OK-</td>
        <td class="emptywithborder single_note">-</td>
        <td class="emptywithborder single_note">-</td>
        <td class="emptywithborder single_note">-</td>
        <td class="empty"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="empty"></td>
        <td class="empty"></td>
        <td class="single_note">OK+</td>
        <td class="emptywithborder single_note">-</td>
        <td class="emptywithborder single_note">-</td>
        <td class="emptywithborder single_note">-</td>
        <td class="empty"></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>20 - TS Hohenems - J1 w</td>
        <td>weiblich</td>
        <td class="emptywithborder"></td>
        <td class="emptywithborder"></td>
        <td class="emptywithborder">13.350</td>
        <td>13.350</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="empty"></td>
        <td class="empty"></td>
        <td class="single_note">E</td>
        <td class="emptywithborder single_note">-</td>
        <td class="emptywithborder single_note">-</td>
        <td class="single_note">7.350</td>
        <td class="empty"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="empty"></td>
        <td class="empty"></td>
        <td class="single_note">D</td>
        <td class="emptywithborder single_note">-</td>
        <td class="emptywithborder single_note">-</td>
        <td class="single_note">4.000</td>
        <td class="empty"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="empty"></td>
        <td class="empty"></td>
        <td class="single_note">C</td>
        <td class="emptywithborder single_note">-</td>
        <td class="emptywithborder single_note">-</td>
        <td class="single_note">2.000</td>
        <td class="empty"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <!--OK minus note-->
        <td class="empty"></td>
        <td class="empty"></td>
        <td class="single_note">OK-</td>
        <td class="emptywithborder single_note">-</td>
        <td class="emptywithborder single_note">-</td>
        <td class="emptywithborder single_note">-</td>
        <td class="empty"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="empty"></td>
        <td class="empty"></td>
        <td class="single_note">OK+</td>
        <td class="emptywithborder single_note">-</td>
        <td class="emptywithborder single_note">-</td>
        <td class="emptywithborder single_note">-</td>
        <td class="empty"></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <table>
    <caption>Jugend 1</caption>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="rank">Rang</th>
        <th class="Team">Team</th>
        <th class="gender"></th>
        <th class="discipline">Boden</th>
        <th class="discipline">Trampolin</th>
        <th class="discipline">Tumbling</th>
        <th class="Total">TOTAL</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>21 - KTV - J1 w</td>
        <td>weiblich</td>
        <td class="emptywithborder">16.400</td>
        <td class="emptywithborder">11.550</td>
        <td class="emptywithborder">12.650</td>
        <td>40.600</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="empty"></td>
        <td class="empty"></td>
        <td class="single_note">E</td>
        <td class="single_note">6.100</td>
        <td class="single_note">6.350</td>
        <td class="single_note">6.650</td>
        <td class="empty"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="empty"></td>
        <td class="empty"></td>
        <td class="single_note">D</td>
        <td class="single_note">6.300</td>
        <td class="single_note">3.200</td>
        <td class="single_note">4.100</td>
        <td class="empty"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="empty"></td>
        <td class="empty"></td>
        <td class="single_note">C</td>
        <td class="single_note">4.000</td>
        <td class="single_note">2.000</td>
        <td class="single_note">1.900</td>
        <td class="empty"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <!--OK minus note-->
        <td class="empty"></td>
        <td class="empty"></td>
        <td class="single_note">OK-</td>
        <td class="emptywithborder single_note">-</td>
        <td class="emptywithborder single_note">-</td>
        <td class="emptywithborder single_note">-</td>
        <td class="empty"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="empty"></td>
        <td class="empty"></td>
        <td class="single_note">OK+</td>
        <td class="emptywithborder single_note">-</td>
        <td class="emptywithborder single_note">-</td>
        <td class="emptywithborder single_note">-</td>
        <td class="empty"></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>20 - TS Hohenems - J1 w</td>
        <td>weiblich</td>
        <td class="emptywithborder"></td>
        <td class="emptywithborder"></td>
        <td class="emptywithborder">13.350</td>
        <td>13.350</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="empty"></td>
        <td class="empty"></td>
        <td class="single_note">E</td>
        <td class="emptywithborder single_note">-</td>
        <td class="emptywithborder single_note">-</td>
        <td class="single_note">7.350</td>
        <td class="empty"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="empty"></td>
        <td class="empty"></td>
        <td class="single_note">D</td>
        <td class="emptywithborder single_note">-</td>
        <td class="emptywithborder single_note">-</td>
        <td class="single_note">4.000</td>
        <td class="empty"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="empty"></td>
        <td class="empty"></td>
        <td class="single_note">C</td>
        <td class="emptywithborder single_note">-</td>
        <td class="emptywithborder single_note">-</td>
        <td class="single_note">2.000</td>
        <td class="empty"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <!--OK minus note-->
        <td class="empty"></td>
        <td class="empty"></td>
        <td class="single_note">OK-</td>
        <td class="emptywithborder single_note">-</td>
        <td class="emptywithborder single_note">-</td>
        <td class="emptywithborder single_note">-</td>
        <td class="empty"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="empty"></td>
        <td class="empty"></td>
        <td class="single_note">OK+</td>
        <td class="emptywithborder single_note">-</td>
        <td class="emptywithborder single_note">-</td>
        <td class="emptywithborder single_note">-</td>
        <td class="empty"></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

**Print preview**

[Print preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/32u8j.png)

Comment: please, attach your css/html related to those tables

Comment: Table related code is now attached, thanks

Comment: Can you also attach some HTML fragment, so we can relate, to actual situation? There might be some structural issue, or other problems, also it would make testing it much easier in playground

Comment: attached. the print version does not work in stackoverflow so you have to make your own html file. the problem is with the page break between page 1 and 2. i use firefox.